# Validate Laravel Nested Rules in Array

Tags: arrays, laravel, validation, nested, rules

I'm with Laravel and I want to write elegant validation rules :) With this Framework its really easy, but I don't know how to approach this when facing 1:n relationships.

I have two Resources, **User** and **Contact**. An User can have multiple Contacts.

So, I want a Form where you can fill all User's fields **AND** all Contact's information.
To do that, I would like to write a Request like this:

UserRequest:

```
public function rules()
    return [
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:exists:users,id',
        'contacts' => 'array',
        'contacts.*' => new ContactRequest() // This is the problem
    ]
```

My question is: How can I apply this type of validation? Specifically when using array, how can I make a Modular Validation to apply validations of nested Resources? Or should I develop a ContactRule instead?

**Edit:**

I want that front end send form like this:

```
` // POST: users
    {
        'name': 'UserName',
        'email': 'user@mail.com'
        'contacts': [
            [
                'email' => 'contac_1@mail.com',
                'contact_type_id => 1
            ],
                        [
                'email' => 'contac_2@mail.com',
                'contact_type_id => 2
            ],

    }
`
```

Thats all,
Thx!

Comment: Please can you show a example of your form and how a user can add additional contact details i.e. with javascript or separate form?

Comment: `contacts.*.email` will work

Comment: Hi! Sorry, I added the summited form data I would like to receive :P I would like to apply a validation over the 'contacts' input array. I its possible to keep validation modular? To let UserRequest.php be as simple as possible , and especially, to reuse same Contact Validation in other Requests

Comment: I don't like `contacts.*.email` because this validation will (and it already is, more complex), `contacts.*.email`, `contacts.*.contact_type_id`, `contact.*...`, etc. And, this Contact validation will be used in multiple Resources, so, I will have duplicated code. thats what I want to avoid with this try of Modularization... I would love to use a single line, like my example :D

Comment: how to validate if the contacts array contains different fields, eg. email1,contact_type_id1, email2, contact_type_id2

Answer (score 2):

We have an API with 100's of results in each request or perhaps post/patch. 
We still use:

```
'data.relationships.users.data.*.id' => [
    'string',
    'unique:api_groups,name,' . ($this->route('group')->id ?? 0),
]
```

So for you

```
'contacts.*.email' => 'required|email|unique:exists:users,id'
```

Works perfectly. It doesn't get more complex or anything.

Comment: Thats fine when its a simple field, or two, but imagine when it grows. For example, 5 fields, `contacts.*.email`, `contacts.*.field_2`, `contacts.*.field_3`, `contacts.*.field_4`, `contacts.*.field_5`, and more.. And, additionally, this will be used in multiple endponits (not only in User endpoint, Model2, Model3, etc). There will be a lot of duplicated code :(

Comment: No there is no duplicate code because you use form requests. 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#form-request-validation

public function storeUser(StoreBlogPost $request)
{
  //Do stuff
}

public function storeModel2(StoreBlogPost $request)
{
  //Do stuff
}